# Magento 2 where is config.xml

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 the `config.xml` is placed under `app/etc`. Where it this file in Magento 2? Is it called `di.xml` instead?

Comment: app/etc/env.php

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Yeah you're actually correct. As I said the `config.xml` is gone. What kind of data do you need this file for ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have created a custom attribute for products. And i want to copy the value of this custom attribute to order items. I can understand it has to be done via the config.xml. am i right?

Comment: Oh ok but you're referring to the module `config.xml` not the `app/etc` file. refer to Kishan answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is in etc/module.xml. It is main module file in Magento2.

For example: `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences in module structure between M1 and M2.
The `app/etc/config.xml` does not exist in M2.
In M1 this file held some default settings used when the app was installed. These options are moved to the installer (not sure exactly where, but you should not even care).
The `app/etc/local.xml` is gone, and the values kept in M1 in there are moved to `app/etc/env.php`.

For a module, the `config.xml` file still exists, but it only contains the config values default values.  What you used to add in the `<default>` tag in M1's `config.xml`.